# Inserting into main div causes unbalance in html

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar & a navbar in my html file. That's all I have. I wanted to insert my content into the div main-content. But when I insert anything into the main-content div. It appears like this -

[image]

I want my content to appear on the empty space.

[image]

What I am using here.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>...</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
         <!--Main Content Here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.sidebar{
    padding-top: 84px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 223px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
    min-width: 120px;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}
.nav-wrapper{
    background-color: white;
    color: #222;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make style for your output so when you add the style in your code it will work like you want.

```
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #f2f2f9;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sidebar {
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 223px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
    min-width: 120px;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
    z-index: 1;
}
.nav-wrapper{
    background-color: white;
    color: #222;
}
nav {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
}
.main-content {
    padding-left: 243px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by shifting my sidebar into a main-container and then adding a padding of -100%. Then i made another division with class content and set its padding to 223px (the width of the sidebar) and adding padding further. If anyone has a better solution please answer!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try as left the content as left & right? Find below a sample i tried

```
        <div class="wrapper">
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav-wrapper">
                        Nav Wrapper
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper-content">
                        <!--Main Content Here-->
                        Main Content
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="sidebar">
                    SideBar
                </div>
            </div>

CSS
        .nav-wrapper {
                    background-color: white;
                    color: #222;
                    z-index: 9999;
                    float: left;
                    margin-bottom: 84px;
                }
    .wrapper-content {
                float: right;
            }
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't fit my needs but still thanks for answering and I already solved my problem!